# Nested form in rails4 anwer field not build to 4.times

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to create a simple app with the following models: Question --[has_many]--> answer_options

I have the following code for creating Question + AnswerOptions

```
<%= simple_form_for @quiz_question do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">       
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :quiz_options do |builder| %>
      <%=builder.input :ans_title%>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This is my controller

```
def new
  @quiz_question = QuizQuestion.new
  4.times{ @quiz_question.quiz_options.build }
end
```

But answer field only builds once.
I am following this tutorial http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1?view=asciicast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem lies in the fact that you have not included `accepts_nested_attributes_for :quiz_options` in your model.

Please include this and see if it works!